# Passing props to a component - syntax error

Tags: reactjs, react-props

from APP.JS, I am trying to call another component CountryPanel  and passing a param to it but getting syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

```
function App(props) {
  var countryCode = window.prompt("Enter Country Code")
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {(countryCode == "gl") ? <InfoPanel /> : <CountryPanel (countryCode = countryCode) />}}
```

Line 52:62:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

50 |
51 |

> 52 |       {(countryCode == "gl") ?  : <CountryPanel (countryCode = countryCode) />}}
> |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here,

```
{(countryCode == "gl") ? <InfoPanel /> : <CountryPanel (countryCode = countryCode) />}}
```

Why are you using first bracket in here, ??

```
<CountryPanel (countryCode = countryCode) />
```

YOu probably meant something like this,

```
<CountryPanel countryCode={countryCode} />
```

Comment: Thanks.. aXuser264 .. Whats the difference in the two?

Comment: I meant whats the difference between: 1. <CountryPanel countryCode={countryCode}
2. <CountryPanel (countryCode = countryCode) />
braces make a difference?

Comment: @nktoronto i couldn't find anything on the 2nd syntax, its just gives me syntax err. I dont think thats a way to pass `props` to component

Comment: the 1st syntax is the one i got from react docs and it works, (note you can do a bit crazy stuff like this `{...somthing}` to a destruct object through)